# Makefile that compiles all cpp files in a directory into separate executable

Tags: c++, makefile

I am now studying C++. I want a makefile which will compile all of the cpp files in the current directory to separate executables. ***For example:***

In a directory there are 3 c++ files, such as **examp1.cpp, examp2.cpp** and **examp3.cpp**. I want a makefile which will compile and link them and give **examp1.exe, examp2.exe** and **examp3.exe**

I have created a bash script to compile all of them and create exes but I think; that's not the exact way to do this.

I have a a Makefile for ".c", but that does not seem to work here. It is only creating object files and not actually linking it. It is as follows:

```
SRCS=$(wildcard *.c)
OBJS=(SRCS:.c=.o)
all: $(OBJS)
```

The above code compiles all the new and modified ".c" files to ".o" files with same name in the current directory.

The bash script I am using to create executables is as follows:

```
for i in ./*.cpp
do
   g++ -Wno-deprecated $i -o `basename $i .cpp`".exe"
done
```

This means I want whatever ".cpp" files I put in that directory, by using a simple "make all" or anything like that it should compile.

Comment: Have you made any attempt at trying to create the makefile? If so post it so we can help you. There is [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) available to get started.

Comment: The versions of make vary from one supplier to another. What make are you using? Are you using GNU Make on Linux? Microsoft Make on Windows/Visual C++?

Comment: Have you tried writing a makefile that will compile *one* source file and produce an executable?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A minimal Makefile that does what you want would be:

```
#Tell make to make one .out file for each .cpp file found in the current directory
all: $(patsubst %.cpp, %.out, $(wildcard *.cpp))

#Rule how to create arbitary .out files. 
#First state what is needed for them e.g. additional headers, .cpp files in an include folder...
#Then the command to create the .out file, probably you want to add further options to the g++ call.
%.out: %.cpp Makefile
    g++ $< -o $@ -std=c++0x
```

You'll have to replace g++ by the compiler you're using and possibly adjust some platform specific setting, but the Makefile itself should work.

Comment: By using this Makefile; for example if I have a file "hello.cpp" I have to use "make hello.out", but I am asking if I use "make all" will compile "hello.cpp" to "hello.out". Here when I use the above Makefile I am getting "Nothing to be done for all"

Comment: Have you tried it? xD It specifies in the second line that the make all command needs one .out file for each .cpp file found in the directory. Therefore a call to make all will make result in a call in e.g. make hello.out, make bye.out, and so on. Sure u can also use make hello.out since the rule is specified, but u don't have to.

Comment: Ok, try once more, I forgot to put $(wildcard *.cpp) in the all rule. Now it should work as expected.

Comment: And if you copy & paste you will have to replace the for spaces in front off "g++" by one tab.

Comment: It worked!. I just misspelled "patsubst" to "pathsubst". I think, that last "$(wildcard *.cpp)" is not needed.

Answer (score 3):

This is the Makefile that I use

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -O2 -std=gnu99 -static -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -rdynamic -fomit-frame-pointer
all: $(patsubst %.c, %.out, $(wildcard *.c))
%.out: %.c Makefile
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ -lm
clean:
    rm *.out
```

You should paste it somewhere in your home and whenever  you change the dirctory just copy it there. I use an alias in my ~/.basrc to copy it

```
alias get_makefile_here='cp ~/Makefile ./'
```

Simply press `make` and bam, you're done. Also notice the fact that once you're done with the old files it will not rebuild their executable.

Answer (score 2):

My answer builds on top of the answer by @Haatschii

I don't prefer to have the `.out` prefix to my binaries. Also I used his existing Make syntax to perform clean as well.

```
CXX=clang++
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -Werror -std=c++11

all: $(patsubst %.cpp, %.out, $(wildcard *.cpp))

%.out: %.cpp Makefile
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $(@:.out=)

clean: $(patsubst %.cpp, %.clean, $(wildcard *.cpp))

%.clean:
        rm -f $(@:.clean=)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest makefile you can create that might work for you is this:

```
all: examp1.exe examp2.exe examp3.exe
```

That will use make's default rules to create your three programs.